# Preencher GRID com JSON - Deserializado (MetroGrid - MetroFramework)

Tags: c#, json, .net, metroframework

provavelmente, estou fazendo algum processo errado, e devo ter errado ao fazer o laço, mas vamos lá.

Eu tenho uma classe chamada 'Classe.cs' que possui o seguinte código:

```
 [JsonProperty("A")]
 public string A{ get; set; }

 [JsonProperty("B")]
 public string B{ get; set; }

 [JsonProperty("C")]
 public string C{ get; set; }
```

Fiz ela desta forma, por conta dos retornos do JSON. Então, na hora de deserializar, apenas informo a classe e o objeto do Array.

**Porém, eu preciso jogar isso num GRID que tenha colunas com nomes diferentes da Classe.
  Ex.: Primeira Coluna -> Dados A que precisa receber o valor A {get; set;}**

Para ser mais exato, o componente é o MetroGrid do MetroFramework. Caso seja necessário, posso mudar o mesmo para DataGridView (dó próprio Tools do Visual Studio)

Eu havia tentando fazer o um loop, informando cada item da List<>, para o nome da Coluna, porém, ele me informa que não é possível fazer esse processo.

Caso eu use o código abaixo:

```
mtrgrdDataGrid.DataSource = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Classe>>(strDados);
```

Ele preenche o DataGrid, de acordo com a coluna do objeto.

Como preencher esse DataGrid, porém, com nomes personalizados nas colunas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você tem várias opções:

Gerando as colunas automaticamente, você vai precisar informar qual o nome será exibido:

```
public class MyClas
{
    [DisplayName("Dados A")]
    public string A { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Dados B")]
    public string B { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Dados B")]
    public string C { get; set; }
}
```

Ou, Caso sejam nomes simples, pode simplesmente renomear a propriedade e usar o JsonProperty como fez, para mapear o json:

```
public class MyClas
{
    [JsonProperty("A")]
    public string DadosA { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("B")]
    public string DadosB { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("C")]
    public string DadosC { get; set; }
}
```

ps. Você ainda pode usar as duas anotações juntas:

```
[JsonProperty("A")]
[DisplayName("Dados A")]
public string DadosA { get; set; }
```

Ou, adicionando as colunas manualmente, você pode definir qual o Header Text e qual Property irá exibir:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

ps. Lembre de desabilitar o `AutoGenerateColumns` após o `InitializeComponent`:

```
dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
```

Comment: Eu acabei optando por usar a última opção. Eu troquei o componente para DataGridView, e fiz exatamente isto daí. E voilá, caiu como uma luva.

Comment: não esqueça de marcar como resposta